Телеграмм бот отправляет видео 16:9 в форме квадрата
Код скачивания видео:
async def download_video(url, size):
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': 'video.mp4',
        'format': f'bestvideo[height={size}][ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best',
        'merge_output_format': 'mp4',  
        'noplaylist': True
    }
    try:
        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info_dict = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)

Код отправления видео:
await bot.send_video(video=FSInputFile("video.mp4"), chat_id=chat_id)

Пример ссылки и качества:
https://vk.com/video-220754053_456241914 / 1080p
Данная проблема возникает при отправке видео высокого качества.
Пробовал в качестве превью ставить 1 кадр видео. Так же пробовал менять метаданные и конкретно указывать формат 16:9 — ничего из этого так и не помогло решить проблему.
Пример того, как приходит видео:

Если видео сохранить в галерею, то оно отображается нормально.
